# Can I get a sequence of bounded functions converging pointwise to $f(x)=1/x$ for $x$ non zero and $0$ for $x$ zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, metric-spaces

How do I construct an explicit sequence of bounded functions converging pointwise to $f(x)=1/x$ for non zero $x$ and $f(0)=0$. It would be better if someone may find a continuous and even better if someone gives a differentiable sequence of functions on $\Bbb R$ converging to $f$ pointwise.

Comment: I just wanted to add. You could also use mollifiers, so just pick $ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1/x, & \mbox{if } x>\frac{1}{n} \\ 0, & \mbox{if } 0\leq n\leq 
\frac{1}{n}\end{cases}$ and apply mollifiers to increase smoothness [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The functions
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+nx^2}
$$
are (infinitely often) differentiable on $\Bbb R$. Each $f_n$ is bounded:
$$
 |f_n(x)| =  \frac{\sqrt{nx^2}}{1+nx^2} \sqrt n \le \frac 12 \sqrt n \, ,
$$
and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ pointwise for all $x$.

Graph of $f_5, f_{10}, f_{40}$ together with the graph of $1/x$:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

How about: $$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1/x, & \mbox{if } x>\frac{1}{n} \\ n^2\cdot x, & \mbox{if } 0\leq x\leq 
\frac{1}{n}\end{cases}
$$
This is continous, though not differentiable, but you can get the idea on how to do it(What I did is just join the point $(\frac{1}{n},n)$ with $(0,0)$ in a continous manner, sure you can come about with a differentiable way and even $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$)

Comment: +1 for the answer and for your quickness.